# A graph which is not a single block has at least two leaf blocks

Tags: graph-theory

> A graph which is not a single block has at least two leaf blocks.

According to the Intro. to Graph Theory by D. West:

- **Block:** A maximal connected subgraph of $G$ that has no cut-vertex.
- **Leaf block:** A block that contains eactly one cut-vertex of $G$.

I have not well understood this statement. Would you elaborate on this statement.

Edit:
Can we say this:

> The block-cutpoint graph of a connected graph is a *tree* where its leaves denote the blocks of $G$. Since a tree has at least two leaf blocks hence the graph has at least two leaf blocks if it is not a single block.

Comment: What is a "block"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I just edited the question.

Comment: Sorry, if you take 2 disjoint $K_3$ as your graph $G$, then $G$ is not a single block but neither of the 2 $K_3$ are leaf blocks?

Comment: @user42493: we assume it is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion in the edit looks sound; that is what I'd do too. (Note, as pointed out in the comments, that you'll need to assume that the graph is connected, but that is commonly considered a requirement for talking about cut vertices at all).

Of course you'll need to furnish some kind of argument (or reference) for the three claims you make:

- That the block-cutpoint graph is a tree.
- That a leaf in the block-cutpoint tree must be a block.
- That a tree that is not a point has at least two leaves.

Comment: I see. Thanks @HenningMakholm.